# Tapestry 5 BeanEditForm component trouble

Tags: tapestry

I am having a bit trouble figuring out how to work with BeanEditForm component. 
You see, everything is fine with it (it displays what it should) as long as i don't use parametrized constructors for my bean class (and i kind a need them). This is how my Bean class looks like:

```
public class Celebrity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long ID;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Occupation occupation;
    private String biography;
    private boolean birthDateVerified;

    public Celebrity() {
    }

    public Celebrity(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, Occupation occupation, String biography, boolean birthDateVerified) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.occupation = occupation;
        this.biography = biography;
        this.birthDateVerified = birthDateVerified;
    }

    public Celebrity(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, Occupation occupation) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }


    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Occupation getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(Occupation occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the biography
     */
    public String getBiography() {
        return biography;
    }


    public void setBiography(String biography) {
        this.biography = biography;
    }

    public boolean getBirthDateVerified() {
        return birthDateVerified;
    }

    public void setBirthDateVerified(boolean birthDateVerified) {
        this.birthDateVerified = birthDateVerified;
    }
}
```

This is my tapestry template: AddNewCelebrity.tml

```
<html t:type="layout" title="Celebrity Details"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

    <head>
        <Title>Adding new celebrety</Title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <t:beaneditform t:id="celebrity"/>
    </body>

</html>
```

And its Java class:

```
public class AddNewCelebrity {

    @Persist
    private Celebrity celebrity;

    public Celebrity getCelebrity() {
        return celebrity;
    }

    public void setCelebrity(Celebrity celeb) {
        this.celebrity = celeb;
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get from tapestry when i don't comment my parametrized constructors:

> Render queue error in SetupRender[AddNewCelebrity:celebrity.editor]: Exception instantiating instance of com.celebreties.celebs.model.Celebrity (for component 'AddNewCelebrity:celebrity.editor'): Error invoking constructor com.celebreties.celebs.model.Celebrity(String, String, Date, Occupation, String, boolean) (at Celebrity.java:29) (for service 'BeanModelSource'): No service implements the interface java.lang.String.

I'm using tapestry 5.2.4 with Tomcat 6.0.32

Please give some guidelines what can I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the BeanEditForm doesn't know what parameters to pass to the constructor. It tries to look for a matching service for each parameter but `No service implements the interface java.lang.String` so it can't be done. I can't really explain why it won't simply use the no-args constructor instead of trying to guess parameters for one of the other constructors.

Nevertheless, you can easily work around this by simply instantiating the object yourself before passing it as a parameter:

```
public Celebrity getCelebrity() {
    if (celebrity == null) {
      celebrity = new Celebrity(...);
    }
    return celebrity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this solved my problem entirely. I was preoccupied looking for some kind of model class, which could be inserted as model component in BeanEditForm. That wasn't such a waste of time, but this is way more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem some time ago.
Please check this thread: http://tapestry-users.832.n2.nabble.com/T5-2-Constructor-issue-td5603058.html

What should help you is to annotate default constructor with @Inject

Regards
Michał

Answer (score 2):

This was recently added as an official FAQ:

http://tapestry.apache.org/beaneditform-faq.html

When you render a BeanEditForm, or when the rendered form is submitted, Tapestry must instantiate an instance of the object to be edited. This occurs when the BeanEditForm's object parameter is bound to null: Tapestry instantiates an instance of the property type so that the BeanEditForm has an object to read default values from, or to push submitted values into.

By default, this uses the standard injection mechanism, which means that Tapestry will identify the public constructor with the most parameters, and attempt to find objects and other objects for each constructor parameter.

There's two ways to fine tune this so you don't get errors:

Place an @Inject annotation on the correct constructor to use (often, the constructor with no parameters).

```
public class MyBean {
   @Inject
   public MyBean() { ... }


   // For testing
   public MyBean(String value, boolean flag, int index) { ... }

   ...
}
```

Or, provide an event handler method for the "prepare" event, and put an instantiated instance into the property.

```
public class MyPage {
  @Property
  public MyBean myBean;

  // The template contains <t:beaneditform t:id="mybeaneditor"/> ...

  void onPrepareFromMyBeanEditor() {
    myBean = new MyBean();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem just a few minutes ago. I am using netbeans and i imported entity classes from databes. Anyway if you imported entity classes IDE generates 3 constructors, and all you really need is one - the empty one, su you can simply erase the other two constructors and it will work fine if you add @Property annotation.

like so:

```
 @Property
 @Persist
 private Celebrity celebrity;
```

and erase those two constructors in entity class!

Regards,
Milos D.

Answer (score -2):

If you need more constructors, just put annotation @Inject above default constructor. You will be able to use constructor with parameters, and Tapestry will use default constructor.